# Applescript one window resizes, the other doesn't

Tags: applescript

I'm getting an unusual result when resizing windows via applescript.

I'm trying to set the position and size of Excel's windows but in one window's case it works and in another it doesn't.

Here's the code:

```
tell application "System Events"
get the name of every application process whose class of windows contains window
repeat with P in the result
    get (every window of process (contents of P) whose value of attribute "AXMinimized" is false)
    repeat with W in the result
        set win_name to name of W
        log P & ":" & win_name

        if (win_name is equal to "VBA-Web - Blank") then
            log "CASE1"
            tell W
                set {position, size} to {{0, 0}, {1100, 500}}
            end tell
        end if

        if (win_name is equal to "Microsoft Visual Basic - VBA-Web - Blank.xlsm - [ThisWorkbook (Code)]") then
            log "CASE2"
            tell W
                set {position, size} to {{0, 0}, {1120, 520}}
            end tell
        end if

    end repeat
end repeat
end tell
```

In the code above, CASE1 works fine, but CASE2 does nothing.
I suspect the VBA editor window is somehow different... but how?

Any suggestions on what I can try to fix this?

Comment: Why are you using _System Events_ ?  If I recall, _Excel_ is scriptable, so you can script the `window` objects of the application directly, and adjust size and position by way of the `bounds` property.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I'll investigate it CJK.